# How to cut lines differently depending on a field in the line

Tags: bash, grep, cut

There is a file that constitutes lines of 2 types. There are some common fields that I want to extract from both types but these fields appear on different positions of a line. How do I make the cut to extract those fields?

For example:

```
Time Type1Identifier UselessField1 UselessField2 UsefulFields...
Time Type2Identifier UselessField3 UsefulFields...
```

How do I cut such that I can extract Time and those UsefulFields and keep the ordering of lines as the original file?

Comment: How can one tell whether a field is useful?

Comment: Use Awk, probably.

Comment: @Beta It sounds like it's hard-coded depending on the identifier in the 2nd field.

Comment: Use a bunch of `awk` blocks that test `$2` against different identifiers, and print the useful fields for each.

Comment: The useful is identified for each type of log by the index.

Comment: I was hoping for something neater than the awk...but it seems awk is the consensus here. Thanks guys!

Comment: You *could* read each line in an array, loop on the array and keep only the "useful" ones.